# Git can't commit Angular folder on my project with IntelliJ or SourceTree

Tags: git, angular, intellij-idea, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a web app project with a folder with a PHP API REST and another folder containing Angular files. When I want to commit my files to BitBucket, I can commit all except the files under the Angular folder.

Same thing on SourceTree, I can't see any changes under this folder. Is there a thing Angular is doing on "ng new angular-app" to force this behaviour ? How can I fix this ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show us the structure of your project, and tell us at what level is your git root (the folder containing the .git). Most likely your folder containing angular code is out of the scope of your git repository.

Comment: That's something I don't understand too : I can't find a .git file

Comment: You won't see the .git folder in IntelliJ. Use an explorer Where is your PHP code? What is in your rest folder? no .git there? In sourcetree, you see the git folder next to project name (that's the one containing the .git folder)

Comment: Okay thanks, so now I can see the .git folder. It was hidden on my Mac. Rest folder contains php files only, there is no .git here

Comment: So your git root is at the right place. You should be able to add your new folder to Git. Can you open a terminal and type `git status` in your project directory? Do you see your folder as untracked files?

Comment: On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 .idea/workspace.xml

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160999/discussion-between-matt-and-mattew-eon).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With the help of Matt, I found how to solve my issue : As I couldn't see hidden files, I didn't see that Angular CLI created a .git folder in the angular app folder. I removed it, and now It's working.

For future apps, if we don't want Angular to initialize a git repo, we can specify it on the creation command like this :
`ng new --skip-git`

Comment: Working! This is fkn unbelievable..... Thanks man, this is just plain ridiculous. Why the hell they did this

Comment: @LiquidCore I think they did this because usually you have one Git for your front-end, and another for your back-end. Maybe it's the way Angular team wanted us to work ?

Comment: @MattewEon They have to ask it, you can't place a hidden repo under my ass without even asking. It's not how work it's done. What the name of the repo is, what are the configurations? They all decide them for me?

Better letting me make my own repo.

Comment: Yeah I can understand this. I found this some days ago, you can create a new Angular project without associating a git file with this command : `ng new --skip-git`